# C++ Overloading << operator in Matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, ostream

I am trying to overload the ostream << operator in my Matrix class, but I keep getting the following error:

Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before token &

```
Matrix::ostream& operator<<(const Matrix& matrix)
{
  for (int r = 0; r < matrix.getNumrows(); r++)
  {
    cout << matrix.getPoint(r, 0);
    for (int c = 0; c < matrix.getNumcolumns(); c++)
    {
      cout << " " << matrix.getPoint(r,c);
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return stream;
}
```

This is the rest of my class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix()
{

}

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    numRows=rows;
    numCols=cols;

    //col=new double[cols];
    mx=new double*[rows];
    for ( int i=0; i < rows; i++ ) {
        mx[i] = new double[cols];
        // initalize each element of the new row.
        for ( int c=0; c < cols; c++ ) {
            mx[i][c] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}


Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &theMatrix) {
    int rows=theMatrix.numRows;
    int cols=theMatrix.numCols;

    numRows = rows;
    numCols = cols;

    mx=new double*[rows];
    for ( int r=0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        mx[r] = new double[cols];
        // copy each element of the new row.
        for ( int c=0; c < cols; c++ ) {
            mx[r][c] = theMatrix.mx[r][c];

        }
    }
}


void Matrix::setMatrix(string file)
{
    /* read the file */
    fstream inputStream(file.c_str());

    if(inputStream.is_open() )
    {
        string line;
        stringstream ss;

        getline(inputStream, line);
        ss.clear();
        ss.str(line);

        ss >> numRows >> numCols;

        mx=new double*[numRows];
        for ( int i=0; i < numRows; i++ ) {
            mx[i] = new double[numCols];
            // initalize each element of the new row.
            for ( int c=0; c < numCols; c++ ) {
                mx[i][c] = 0.0;
            }
        }


        //now loop to get values
        for(int row=0; row<numRows; row++)
        {
            getline(inputStream, line);
            ss.clear();
            ss.str(line);

            //now get every value in the line
            for(int col=0; col<numCols; col++)
            {
                double current;
                ss >> current;
                mx[row][col] = current;



            }//end reading values of row

        }//end reading rows

    }

    //close the file
    inputStream.close();
}

int Matrix::getNumrows()
{
    return numRows;
}

int Matrix::getNumcolumns()
{
    return numCols;
}

void Matrix::printPoint()
{
    for ( int r=0; r < numRows; r++ )
    {
        for ( int c=0; c < numCols; c++ )
        {
            cout << mx[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

}

bool Matrix::getIsSquared()
{
    if( numRows == numCols )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

 double Matrix::det()
 {
    double det=0.0;
    if(numRows!=numCols)
    {
        cout << "Number Rows must be same as number Colums\n";
    }

    if(numRows==2)
    {
        det=(mx[0][0]*mx[1][1])-(mx[0][1]*mx[1][0]);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<numCols ; i++)
        {
            Matrix temp(numRows-1,numCols-1);
            for(int j=0 ; j<numRows-1 ; j++)
            {
                for(int k=0 ; k<numCols-1 ; k++)
                {
                    if(k<i)
                        temp.mx[j][k]=mx[j+1][k];
                    else
                        temp.mx[j][k]=mx[j+1][k+1];
                }
            }
            det+=pow(-1.0,i)*mx[0][i]*temp.det();
        }
    }
    return det;
 }

 double Matrix::getPoint(int row, int col)
 {
     return mx[row][col];
 }

Matrix Matrix::operator +(const Matrix &right) const
{
    Matrix result(numRows,numCols);
    if ( right.numRows != numRows || right.numCols != numCols )
    {
        cout << "\nError while adding matricies, the two must have the same dimentions.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for ( int r=0; r < numRows; r++ )
        {
            for ( int c=0; c < numCols; c++ )
            {
                result.mx[r][c] = (this->mx[r][c]) + (right.mx[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: When you read from an input stream, you need to be sure to handle any errors that might occur (for example, if the input data doesn't match the format you are expecting).  This is done by testing the state of the stream after each input operation.  Your C++ book should cover how this works in detail.  Consider using some form of smart pointer or a standard library container like `std::vector` for the storage used by your matrix class.  As written, your class is not exception safe and it's quite likely there are errors in your manual memory management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to overload the ostream `operator<<` for your class, you need to use either a friend function or a non-member function because the `ostream` object appears on the left-hand side of the expression (it's written as `os << my_matrix`).

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix& matrix) { /* ... */ }
```

It *looks* like you are trying to implement it as a member function, but that should actually look like:

```
std::ostream& Matrix::operator<<(const Matrix& matrix) { /* ... */ }
```

This won't work because when you implement an operator overload as a member function, the type of the object on the left hand side of the expression is the same as the type of the class of which the overload is a member (so, in this case, you'd have to write `my_matrix1 << my_matrix2`, which isn't what you want).

Inside of the overload, you shouldn't write to `cout` directly; you should write to the `ostream` object that is passed as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Write it as:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix& matrix) 
{ 
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.getNumrows(); r++) 
    { 
        os << matrix.getPoint(r, 0); 
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix.getNumcolumns(); c++) 
        { 
            os << " " << matrix.getPoint(r,c); 
        } 
        os << endl; 
    } 
    return os; 
}
```

and it will work. It does not have to be a member function of Matrix.

Comment: That fixed that, but now I am getting:

Comment: error: passing ‘const Matrix’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Matrix::getNumrows()’ discards qualifiers|

Comment: @Tony:  If you want to call a member function on a const-qualified object, you need to const-qualify the member function.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
Matrix::ostream& operator<<(const Matrix& matrix)
```

to

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &stream, const Matrix &matrix)
```

It'll be a stand-alone function .. and should work just fine.